# Connecting Access to Java DB

Tags: ms-access, javadb

I have a Database which was created using Java DB, Would it be possible for me to manipulate this Database using access?Ive tried using the wizard but it asks me for a dsn and I cant seem to figure out where to get that from

Edit: I would like to modify the database from both MS-Access and javadb

The tables are (relatively) simple currently & it contains 2 relationships; one to zero/one and one to many

Should I convert it to csv and then after I'm finished convert it back to Java DB again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options.  If you want to be able to modify the database from both Derby and MS-Access, then you will need to locate an ODBC driver for MS-Access that would enable it to read and modify a Derby database.  Off hand, I do not know if such a driver exists.

If you wish to simply convert the database to an MS-Access format, then ...

... much will depend on the structure of the underlying tables and how much of the schema you need to preserve.

The simplest thing would be that you have a database consisting of a single table that resembles a flat-file database.  In this case, you can write a simple JDBC tool to write your database out as a CSV file (for example) that MS-Access can read.

If you have multiple tables or data that can't be easily represented by a CSV file, then things become more complex.  You haven't told us anything about your needs or the structure of your database, so it is unlikely that anyone can be more specific.